# HTML content is not same while reading from python requests library

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

**HTML code from brower:**
[image]

**Html code from python requests library:**

```
<p class="text-muted ">
            <span class="certificate">12</span>
            <span class="ghost">|</span> 
            <span class="runtime">192 min</span>
            <span class="ghost">|</span> 
            <span class="genre">Action, Adventure, Fantasy</span>
    </p>
```

**Code:**

```
import requests

base_url = "https://www.imdb.com"
search_url = base_url + "/search/title/?"
params = {
    "title_type": "feature",
    "release_date": "2022-01-01,2022-12-31",  # Movies released in the past 1 year
    "start": 1  # Starting page number
}

# Send GET request to IMDb search page
# response = urllib.request.urlopen(search_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(params))
response = requests.get(search_url, params=params)
print((response.text))
```

How to get the exact html code?
I have tried `urllib.request` with no help.

Comment: use selenium you can simulate browser environment

Comment: I will be using `beautifulsoup` to scrap data further, what could be the reason that it miss some information in normal get request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set `Accept-Language` HTTP header to `en-US`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.imdb.com"
search_url = base_url + "/search/title/"
params = {
    "title_type": "feature",
    "release_date": "2022-01-01,2022-12-31",  # Movies released in the past 1 year
    "start": 1,
}

headers =  {
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'
}


response = requests.get(search_url, params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for title in soup.select('h3')[:10]:
    print(f"{title.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '):<60} {title.find_next(class_='certificate').text:<10}")
```

Prints:

```
1. Avatar: The Way of Water (2022)                           PG-13     
2. The Blackening (2022)                                     R         
3. X (II) (2022)                                             R         
4. Sisu (2022)                                               R         
5. A Man Called Otto (2022)                                  PG-13     
6. Top Gun: Maverick (2022)                                  PG-13     
7. Chevalier (2022)                                          PG-13     
8. The Batman (2022)                                         PG-13     
9. Sanctuary (I) (2022)                                      R         
10. Everything Everywhere All at Once (2022)                 R
```

---

For example for `de-DE` header I get:

```py
headers =  {
    'Accept-Language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.5'
}

...
```

Prints:

```
1. Avatar: The Way of Water (2022)                           12        
2. The Blackening (2022)                                     R         
3. X (II) (2022)                                             16        
4. Sisu: Rache ist süss (2022)                               18        
5. Ein Mann namens Otto (2022)                               12        
6. Top Gun: Maverick (2022)                                  12        
7. Chevalier (2022)                                          PG-13     
8. The Batman (2022)                                         12        
9. Sanctuary (I) (2022)                                      R         
10. Everything Everywhere All at Once (2022)                 16
```